Baer's definition of $S$-characteristic subgroup
I am reading a part of Baer's paper Groups without proper isomorphic quotients, Bull. AMS,50 (1944) 267-278. In that paper, he also discusses groups without proper isomorphic subgroups, which he calls $S$-groups, what we would now call co-Hopfian groups. As part of the discussion, he gives the definition of an $S$-characteristic subgroup: a subgroup of $G$ that is carried into itself by every isomorphism of $G$ into itself. I am well-aware of the definition of characteristic subgroup: one carried into itself by every automorphism of $G$.
My question concerns the interpretation of the phrase "isomorphism into." I seem to recall this being older terminology for what we would now call an injection. Am I correct in this assumption? Given that $S$-group is synonymous with co-Hopfian group, this seems a reasonable interpretation.

The old meaning of "isomorphism" probably did not require surjectivity. An "isomorphism" from $G$ to $H$ in that old sense is equivalently just an isomorphism from $G$ to some subgroup of $H$ in the modern sense.

@GeoffreyTrang - Thanks for the comment. I need something more concrete than "probably," although I agree with you. It brings back a memory of "isomorphism into" vs. "isomorphism onto."

I believe the answer to my question is YES as mentioned in Mariano's comments to the MSE post at What is the difference between "into isomorphism"and "onto isomorphism"?
